# grouping sorted ascending integer sequences - revised

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function that seems to work fine. (On second thought, it missed connecting the first two groups...I'll have to think more about that.)

```
import Data.List (groupBy)

makeGroups xs = 
  map concat $ groupBy (\a b -> head b == last a + 1) (groupBy mGroups0 xs)
    where mGroups0 = \a b -> a == length xs && elem b [1,2] 
                             || b /= length xs && b == a + 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
*Main> makeGroups [3,4,5,6,7,8,1,9,10,2]
[[3,4,5,6],[7,8],[1],[9,10,2]]
```

(Thank you all for the answer about the tabs...now I'm asking for just general coding genius)

Might there be more efficient/convenient ways to group sorted ascending integer sequences in a list (keeping the original order)?

The only extra stipulation is that:

```
the possible groups [length xs] [1] [2] [1,2] [length xs,1] [length xs,2] 
must be separated, but [length xs, 1, 2] should join any larger sequence.
```

Comment: Any reason why you write the local functions with lambda syntax? This is a bit irritating, to say the least.

Comment: @Ingo It's not important to me. I just thought I'd try it this time to see if it works at all.

Comment: Second guess: do you have any tabulator characters in the source code?

Comment: @Ingo hmm...what are tabulator characters? oh tabs? Actually I might...let me check

Comment: The characters inserted when you press the TAB key?

Comment: Usually, you know them when you go over the text with cursor keys and the cursor jumps 4 or 8 characters instead of 1.

Comment: Compiles here when copy-pasted => I bet on tabs. Yup, in your post, there's a tab at the start of the `mGroups1` line.

Comment: @Ingo yup it was the tabs. Thanks!

Comment: This error is so common - GHC should really hint at it ....

Comment: @Ingo `-fwarn-tabs`; unfortunately not on by default :(

Comment: @DanielFischer indeed, this is kinda paradoxical, as you want the warnings only if you know that tabs may be a problem, but exactly that is most often not the case.

Comment: @Ingo To my dismay, I just discovered that it's not even implied by `-Wall`. I'd prefer if there was an `-fallow-tabs` switch to be turned on.

Comment: I don't understand your criteria, I must say. Why `[[3,4,5,6],[7,8],[1],[9,10,2]]`, and not `[[3,4,5,6,7,8],[1],[9,10,2]]`, why the comparisons with `length xs` in `mGroups0`? What's the idea?

Comment: @DanielFischer ha, [7,8] should be grouped with the previous group, the present algorithm missed that. As for length xs, the algorithm involves a complication - the possible groups `[length xs,1]` `[length xs,2]` must be separated, but `[length xs, 1, 2]` should be part of a larger sequenced group

Comment: Are your criteria always considering adjacent elements?

Comment: @DanielFischer not sure what you mean...I'd like to group only sequences of the kind i,i+1,i+2...etc. (including single element groups) except for the special case I explained about length xs

Comment: But to determine whether in the list `...:a:b:...` the two shall be in different groups or the same, is it necessary to look at any elements besides `a` and `b`, or are only those (and some semi-global constants/functions) necessary?

Comment: @DanielFischer it seems that a and b should be enough. The only extra stipulation is the possible groups `[1,2]` `[length xs,1]` `[length xs,2]` must be separated, but `[length xs, 1, 2]` should join any larger sequence.

Comment: So e.g. `[4,5,6,2,3,4]` should produce `[[4,5],[6,2],[3,4]]`, but `[4,5,6,1,2,3]` should produce `[[4,5,6,1,2,3]]`?

Comment: @DanielFischer bingo (I think the list will always include 1..n, that is, 1 will not be missing)

Comment: Urk. Btw, then `[9,10,2]` should be two groups `[9],[10,2]`, shouldn't it? Re "Urk": then you can't simply deciding by looking only at `a` and `b`. That makes things far more complicated to treat with generality. Still, can you describe your criteria abstractly?

Comment: @DanielFischer what you mean by abstractly? I was just getting going with the code and appreciate your effort. One idea I had was to start with the generality and then separate out the complicated groups.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26190/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-groovy)

Comment: @DanielFischer something like this to start with? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417425/grouping-sorted-ascending-integer-sequences-revised/15420638#15420638

Answer (score 1):

something like this? (Thanks to Daniel Fischer's suggestions)

```
makeGroups xs = foldr comb [[last xs]] (init xs) where
  comb a b = if a == head (head b) - 1
                then (a:head b) : tail b
                else [a] : b


*Main> makeGroups [3,4,5,6,7,8,1,9,10,2]
[[3,4,5,6,7,8],[1],[9,10],[2]]
```

And here's a stab at the ugly:

```
makeGroups xs = foldr comb [[last xs]] (init xs) 
  where n = length xs
        ngroup = [1,2,n]
        comb a b = let (x:xs) = head b in 
          if a == n && isPrefixOf [1,2] (x:xs)
             then if not (null $ tail b) && head (head $ tail b) == 3
                     then ((n:head b) ++ (head $ tail b)) : drop 1 (tail b)
                     else (n:head b) : tail b
             else if a == n && isPrefixOf [2,1] (x:xs)
                     then if null (drop 1 xs)
                             then [n,2,1] : tail b
                             else [n,2,1] : drop 1 xs : tail b
             else if elem a ngroup
                     then if elem x ngroup
                             then if null xs
                                     then [a,x] : tail b
                                     else [a,x] : xs : tail b
                             else [a] : b
             else if a /= n && a == x - 1
                     then if x /= n
                             || isPrefixOf [n,1,2] (x:xs)
                             then (a:x:xs) : tail b
                             else [a] : b
                     else [a] : b
```

Comment: It's a start, but the rules for `length xs` make it more complicated.

Comment: Uh, that's really ugly. One thing is that you should bind `n = length xs` outside `comb`, there's no point in risking it to be recomputed. Another thing is that it's not lazy enough (that was also the case for the first stab), by having the `if not (null b)` at the top, you're forcing the entire list to be traversed before anything gets done. Let me see if I can make it shorter and lazier.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh, thanks! but I don't know how to add the first element to the foldr accumulator without the null check

Comment: Hmm, what I have is not shorter, I doubt it's more readable, though it's neat in that it doesn't need post-processing the `foldr` result, and the additional laziness by returning `(a:h):t` before investigating `comb`'s second argument is only important if the lists are long - didn't consider that due to the `length`, we can't have infinite lists, and have the entire list in memory anyway. Not sure if it's worth posting.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you for your comments. How can i get rid of the null check? I seem to get a head empty list error without it, I think because foldr is testing an empty accum...oh i get it...place the last element of the list in the accum to start! regarding the post-processing- an extra condition i was too lazy to write would make it superfluous. I guess i'll add it

Comment: `comb a b = (a:h) : t where (h,t) = convoluted logic`, return a constructor application, and figure out the components later. An important technique when dealing with infinite or very long lists. That way, the `foldr` can start producing output immediately. But if the lists are not longer than a few thousand elements, it's probably not worth the bother here, since the `length` computation forces the entire list to be in memory anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh, that may be beyond me at this point but i'll keep the idea in mind. It's probably ok for this purpose. cool